# What is $L$ for a ring Electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, notation

I am looking at the force equation for an electromagnet from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet):

$$F=\frac{\mu^2N^2I^2A}{2\mu_0L^2}.$$

I'm not sure what $L$ is. It seems like this would be the length of a bar (specifically of the core of the bar) if $I$ was making a bar electromagnet. I want to make a ring electromagnet, though.

The inner diameter will be 9 inches and the outer diameter will be 10 inches. Is the length just the difference in radius (10-9=1 inch) ?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I basically just want an approximate value.

Someone commented that the flux path is average circumference. Wouldn't that be:

$2*\pi*(10$ inch $-9$ inch$)=0.15959$ meters ?

Say I'm using iron (mu is .25), 500 turns, 1 Amp (which I know is a lot), and area is 0.04 m^2 (from radius values). If I just assume L is .15959, the force is huge. Doesn't make sense.

$\frac{(.25^2*500^2*1^2*.04)}{(2*0.000001256637061*.15959^2)}=9.764 × 10^9$ Newtons?

Here is a picture of what I mean (The pink area is where I'd like to find the force):

[image]

Comment: Forget about my answer - I though you were after the inductance.

Comment: It says in the article that it is "length of the flux path" and earlier "average length of the magnetic circuit".   If you look at the diagram of a typical electromagnet with the green magnetic field lines, the flux path is drawn on the diagram as a blur dash-dot line. So in you case it is the average circumference.

Comment: @Farcher thanks! I have updated my question. Not making sense the large number I get

Comment: The average circumference would be $2\pi \times 9.5in = 2\pi \times 0.24m \approx 1.5m$. The cross-sectional area is much smaller: $A = 1in \times 1in = 0.45\times 10^{-4}m^2$ assuming a 1inx1in square cross section of the ring.With these values, I calculate a force of $4\times 10^5$N, but no guarantees about the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Equation Analysis

$L$ comes from the equation of a magnetic field produced from a solenoid:
$$B=μnI$$
where $I$ is the current, $μ$ is the magnetic permeability of the material through which the magnetic field is forming, and $n$ is the number of turns per length of wire $n=N/L$

However, what you are using isn't a solenoid it is a toroid, thus you need to use a different equation.

The magnetic field produced by a toroid, $B$, is (Note the similarity between magnetic field produced by toroid and solenoid):
$$B=μNI/{2πr}$$

Where $r$ is the midpoint radius between the outter radius and the inner radius as shown by this picture:

[image]

### Calculation with given parameters

1. Magnetic Field of Toroid

Given:
$I= 1 A$, $N= 500Turns $ , $μ=0.25 , $r=9.5 inches= 0.2413 meters$

$$B={0.25)(500)(1)}/{(2)(π)(0.2413)}$$
$$B=82.446 T$$

However, note that the magnetic field only exists inside the toroid's core itself which could be verified by ampere's law thus you wouldn't be able to use it to impose an effective magnetic force on any external system

2. Force on required shaded area

[image]

Thus $B$ in shaded area is zero and $Fb=0$

Comment: Wow I love the picture you included and the detail you put in! Again, however I am worried about the final value. How can such a small ring give off that much force!? Also can you explain how you get the area of the core? Is it just A=π(R^2﹣r^2) in your picture π(b^2﹣a^2)?  You have it as 1 m^2.

Comment: I am making some changes right now, with the first being that the values for the magnetic permeability used were inaccurate, and this is what made the force seem huge. As of for the area it is the cross sectional area of the material that you are applying a force to

Comment: Sweet, so if I slide a cylinder in the middle of the toroid, it's the area of contact? Also you use mu_0 twice. One of them should be mu which is around .25 for iron as shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29

Comment: If your aim is to slide a cylinder for some sort of magnetic interaction in the middle of the electromagnet a toroid would be of no use since, the magnetic field in any area outside of the core is zero( i.e in the middle or to the outside), thus the cylinder wouldn't be subject to any force. Sorry I seemed to have understood your question in a wrong way I'll adjust my response accordingly.

Comment: What? Isn't that the purpose of an electromagnetic, to pull things outside of the core?

Comment: Not necessarily, an electromagnet is a system that produces a magnetic field in response to the flow of charge through it. If what you are looking for is pump action, then you are looking at very specific types of electromagnets, which have magnetic fields in their interior. Of which, a solenoid is probably the best DIY option. If you decide to use a solenoid I'd be happy to help you make the necessary calculations

Comment: Thatd be awesome. I think what im trying to make is a Toroidal solenoid. What am I missing here that would make it a solenoid. And definitely interested in the calculations as well

Comment: You would need a different core because your iron core is a closed loop, so you would be looking at a core that is cylinder like and open from both ends fro your use. Also note that the cylinder shouldn't be of any specific material since we don't really care about its magnetic permeability because the dominant magnetic field will theoretically be produced in the interior of the solenoid which contains air.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58159/discussion-between-seth-kitchen-and-honda).